# How to dynamically modify the values inside an array according to a length of a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array

```
passcodeArray: [null, null, null, null],
```

and a variable

```
passcode: '',
```

and I want the index of the array to behave dynamically based on the length of **passcode**

For instance, when

```
passcode.length === 2

passcodeArray: [true, true, true, null],
```

When the length of passcode is reduced to 1, the array needs to be updated to

```
passcodeArray: [true, true, null, null],
```

This is what I have done so far, I'm thinking of a way to incorporate some logic inside my render function

```
renderPasscodeIndicator() {
let views = []
let passcodeArray = this.state.passcodeArray;
let passcodeLength = this.state.passcode.length;

passcodeArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  views.push(
    {
      ...passcodeArray[index] === null ?
      <View key={index} style={[styles.passcodeIndicator]} /> :
      <View key={index} style={[styles.passcodeIndicator, 
    styles.passcodeEntered]} />
        }
      )
    });
    return views;
  }
```

Comment: why don't you just use a for loop?  
so e.g. you always want to push 4 items to views then iterate over 4 + check if i > passcodeLength

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer leo had provided is certainly helpful but it does not update the array in real time.

So, I have decided to put the knowledge I gained in my University into good use.

This is what I got after some good hours.

I use the concept of stack and the all I want to achieve is just comparing the stack length and a loop so that the view could be updated.

```
renderPasscodeIndicator() {
let views = []
let passcodeLength = this.state.passcode.length;

let localStack = []
for (var i=0; i<passcodeLength; i++) {
  localStack.push('x')
}

for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
  views.push({
    ...localStack.length > j ?
    <View key={j} style={[styles.passcodeIndicator, styles.passcodeEntered]} /> :
    <View key={j} style={[styles.passcodeIndicator]} />
  })
}

  return views;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and execute `passcodeArray.fill(true, 0, passcode.length);`

Here is a working example

```js
const passcode = 'test';
const passcodeArray = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null];

const result = passcodeArray.fill(true, 0, passcode.length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, array.fill works only when the operation is static. For instance, I have 4 digits, user have key in 2 passcodes, and he deletes one, so passcode in the stack becomes one, which does not update the result array.